# error while loading shared libraries

Tags: eclipse, qt

My problem is very weird. I am developing in eclipse using QT lib and gtest on ubuntu 11.04.

I am getting `error while loading shared libraries: libRtdb.so.1` only while i wish to Debug. Run works without a problem. I have my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set, without it Run doesn't work.

Are there any separated settings in eclipse for Run and Debug? It's weird since it doesn't work randomly. I have set whole environment on virtual machine, same steps and it worked. Did the same on another virtual machine and it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think i solved it! I added RPATH in my QT project. `QMAKE_RPATHDIR += /usr/mylib`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was investigating the problem some more since the previous solution didn't work so well.
Seems like my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is being reset somewhere.

Unfortunately i didn't find where, so atm my temporary solution will have to be the following:
Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in terminal and running eclipse from there.

See:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=204818&#msg_204818
http://code.google.com/p/xuggle/issues/detail?id=81

Comment: You could also try right clicking on project -> Debug As -> Debug Configuration -> Debug. Should work with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set in eclipse only.